# Is there a way to enumerate interfaces using NI Daqmx

Tags: c++, nidaqmx, daq-mx

I have a C++ application interfacing with a NI DAQ card, however the name of the device is hard coded and if changed in the NI Max app it would stop working, so is there a way to enumerate connected devices to know the name of the cards that are connected ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

List of all devices can be retrieved with `DAQmxGetSysDevNames()`. The names are separated by commas.

Once you have the list of all names, you can use the product type to find the correct device.

```
const std::string expectedProductType = "1234";
constexpr size_t bufferSize = 1000;
char buffer[bufferSize] = {};
if (!DAQmxFailed(DAQmxGetSysDevNames(buffer, bufferSize))) {
    std::string allNames(buffer);
    std::vector<std::string> names;
    boost::split(names, allNames, boost::is_any_of(","));
    for (auto name : names) {
        char buffer2[bufferSize] = {};
        if (!DAQmxFailed(DAQmxGetDevProductType(name.c_str(), buffer2, bufferSize))) {
            if (expectedProductType == std::string(buffer2)) {
                // match found
            }               
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot, I did not come across that function searching through the documentation.
this does provide the functionality I am seeking.